# Pull array results from var_dump in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

I have an AXL query which returns the names of device(s).  When I try and display this information in my webpage it is outputting more info than needed.  Here is the current code:

```php
$payload = array(
    "userid" => "$_POST[iduser]",
    "returnedTags" => array(
        "associatedDevices" => "",
        "device" => ""
    )
);

$response = $client->getUser($payload);
print_r ($response);
```

Output:

```
stdClass Object ( 
  [return] => stdClass Object ( 
    [user] => stdClass Object ( 
      [associatedDevices] => stdClass Object ( 
        [device] => Array ( 
          [0] => SEP5065F3B9AB95 
          [1] => SEPB00CD1D0047D 
        ) 
      ) 
      [uuid] => {29C4300A-AC63-E9C6-F240-CDF7F0DBF153} 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

I am only needing the entries of the devices starting with "SEP".

Additionally, when I hard code the array I get the data I am looking for, however this is not acceptable as there may be more or less than 2 results:

```php
echo '<b>MAC Address : </b>'; 
echo $array['return']['user']['associatedDevices']['device'][0];
echo '<br><br>';
echo '<b>MAC Address : </b>'; 
echo $array['return']['user']['associatedDevices']['device'][1];
echo '<br><br>';
```

Any help on this would be greatly welcome.  I also looked into using a foreach but was unable to return results of that as well.

Thanks!

Comment: That's `print_r` not `var_dump`.

Comment: And your hardcoded "arrays" won't work with those objects.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474722/using-array-walk-recursive-for-stdclass-objects might help

Comment: `"$_POST[iduser]"`  there is absolutely no reason to wrap this in quotes. Simply use `"userid" => $_POST["iduser"]`

Comment: Thank you all for the tips and advise.  Still learning this stuff and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't show your loop attempt, but with those objects and array:

```
foreach($response->return->user->associatedDevices->device as $device) {
    echo $device . '<br><br>';
}
```

Or if it is this simple, then join them with the `<br>`:

```
echo implode('<br><br>', $response->return->user->associatedDevices->device);
```

Comment: It's an object, not an array.

Comment: I see, their hardcoded echos make no sense then.